# HTML5 Validation issue

Tags: regex, html, validation, input, pattern-matching

I'm trying to validate input using HTML5 `pattern` tag.
Have 3 separate input checks:

- upper or lower case characters from a-e range, 1 character limit `[A-Ea-e]{1}`
  For example: A, B, e ...
- only numbers and comma. Comma is not first or last character of string. `[0-9]+,*[0-9]+` For example: 0,52356, 0677,67 ...
- upper or lower case characters from a-e range, 1 character limit `[A-Ea-e]{3}` for example: AbE, cDa

I want to add to all of this samples `or * sign with 1 char limit` condition.

For every check that listed above there might be 1 * sign which is also accepted. But if there is * sign, adding more characters must end with invalid result.

I'm new to regex. Can not figure out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @frosty http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @demonoid: What do you mean by "samples"? Strings that should be matched? Please provide exact examples, those that are valid. Your second condition is too obscure. Numbers and a comma - `[0-9,]*`?

Comment: @stribizhev updated question

Comment: I do not understand *For every check that listed above there might be 1 * sign which is also accepted*. Try [`[a-eA-E]{3}|[a-eA-E]|\d+(?:,\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/sZ4mV9/1) and let me know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Do you just want to allow a `*` at the end with all allowed value types? Please [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gnwpx57/).

Comment: Please let me know if my fiddle works for you, I will post it then. I see the identical solution has been posted below, but it does not account for the fact that the HTML5 pattern attribute regex is already anchored (that is why it is identical to mine).

Answer (score 1):

```
^([A-Ea-e]{1}|[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*|[A-Ea-e]{3})\*?$
```

Valid:

```
A
AAA
1
1,2
1,2,3
A*
AAA*
1*
1,2*
1,2,3*
```

Invalid:

```
AA
AAAA
,1
1,
1,**
```

If you want them separate:

```
^[A-Ea-e]{1}\*?$
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*\*?$
^[A-Ea-e]{3}\*?$
```

Comment: Note that my regular expressions doesn't allow `1,,2` while yours would.  I'm not sure if that is correct or not.